# Hyperref in mathematical equations

Tags: formatting, hyperref, cross-referencing

With the following codes:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]

\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

 \begin{equation}\label{eq}
  x+y=z
 \end{equation}

In view of \eqref{eq}, we have

    \end{document}
```

I get

[image]

> I hope that the brackets will be also **automatically** colorated like the number of the equation. As it is shown also in this paragraph of a paper:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to redefine `\eqref` to use `\hyperref[<link>]{... \ref*{<link>} ...}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}

\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\makeatletter
% \newcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[#1]{\textup{\tagform@{\ref*{#1}}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  x+y=z \label{eq}
\end{equation}

In view of \eqref{eq}, we have \ldots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Same answer than for your previous question: instead of worrying about such things, let `cleveref` do it for you:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]

\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

 \begin{equation}\label{eq}
  x+y=z
 \end{equation}

In view of \labelcref{eq}, we have

    \end{document}
```

[image]